# When I run vite preview I get the bundle size of 300KB and when I run vite build it creates a bundle with 900KB

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, bundler, vite, rollup

I am using Vite in a react project.

Versions -

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"vite": "^3.0.0",
"@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.0",
```

Here is my `vite.config.js`

```js
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
  },
});
```

Here is my `package.json` scripts -

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "prettier": "prettier src -check",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
```

When I do `npm run preview` and open a site in the browser I get bundle of size `301KB`.
But when I do `npm run build` it gives me bundle size of `986KB`!
If `vite preview` is intended to preview the site as in production why `vite build` is not giving me the bundle with the same size when I build?

When I build it shows following messages -

[image: messages after build]

Also, What is the meaning of `986.76 KiB / gzip: 292.94 KiB`?

Comment: The first number is the **raw** size. The second number is the **compressed** size (with gzip). Files are typically served compressed, so the browser's devtools will typically show the compressed size. I suspect that's what you're observing. The `301KB` you noted is not far off from `292.94 KiB` indicated in the build output.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by @tony19, the first number is the **raw** size, which is the actual size of the file.  The second number is the **compressed** size after compressing with gzip.

When you build vite with `npm run build`, by default, no compression is applied.

In many cases, your webserver will handle compression for you, so this isn't an issue.

However, in some cases you will want to do the compression yourself:

- If your webserver does not support compression (you are on a shared host and can't change server settings, for example)
- If you have a static app and want to compress things in advance

In such cases, you can use [vite-plugin-compression2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-compression2?activeTab=versions).

Why use this plugin? Because vite-plugin-compression is no longer getting updates, and vite-plugin-compression2 lets you compress to both gzip and brotli (the more efficient brotli for all chrome-based browsers, and gzip for Safari):

**vite.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig, type PluginOption } from 'vite'
import compression from 'vite-plugin-compression2';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    compression({
      algorithm: 'gzip', exclude: [/\.(br)$ /, /\.(gz)$/]
    }),
    compression({
      algorithm: 'brotliCompress', exclude: [/\.(br)$ /, /\.(gz)$/],
     }),
  ],
})
```